# Word 2013: Use dot as decimal separator

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am using `Word 2013` on `Windows 7`. Keyboard layout is `Finnish` and Windows language is `English`. I want to use dot as decimal separator instead of comma in `MS Word`.

I have set decimal separator to `.` from `Region and language > Additional settings > Decimal symbol` on both Numbers and Currecy tabs.

After this change `Excel 2013` changes decimal separator to `.` from `,`. but Word keeps still using `,` when pressing comma button of numpad.

According to information I have found Word should respect the Region and language settings like Excel does.

I have also looked trough Word settings but haven't found anything related to decimal separator.

How can I make Word to to use `.` as decimal separator?